# Angular 2: How do I handle templateUrl failure

Tags: javascript, angular

How can we handle templateUrl failure? like redirect to a default route if template fails.

In this case I have implemented a templateUrl function like;

```
@Component({
selector: 'oauth-home',
templateUrl: AppSettings.VIEW_OAUTHHOME_ENDPOINT + '?access_token=' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('access')).access_token,
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ControlMessages],
providers: [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]
})
```

When the access_token missing or expired the template url throws an error. In that case I need to redirect authentication failed view, within the fail callback.